# Scattered data set in statistical data analysis

Tags: java, statistics, mean, scatter

I have some number of statistical data. Some of the data are very scattered to the majority of data set as shown below. What I want to do is minimize the effect of highly scattered data in the data set. I want to compute mean of the data set which has minimized effect of the scattered data in my case.

```
My data set is as like this:
10.02, 11, 9.12, 7.89, 10.5, 11.3, 10.9, 12, 8.99, 89.23, 328.42.
```

As shown in figure below:
[image: One data is scattered as shown below(say)]

I need the mean value which is not 46.3 but closer to other data distribution.
Actually, I want to minimize the effect of 89.23 & 328.42 in mean calculation.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try asking this at http://math.stackexchange.com or http://stats.stackexchange.com . Your question as it stands is not really related to programming and you will probably get a faster response at those other sites

Comment: Searched so many times already. But couldn't find suitable solution.
I am working in project, statistical data analysis. This is a problem what I am facing since last few months. thanks anyway @mathematician1975

Comment: specially this site for programming question as @mathematician1975 mentioned. But I think this also seems good conceptual question regarding to mathematical,statistical and also programming aspect.Hope some geek will give very intelligent answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might notice that you really dont want the mean. The problem here is that the distribution you've assumed for the data is different from the actual data. If you are trying to fit a normal distribution to this data you'll get bad results. You could try to fit a heavy tailed distribution like the cauchy to this data. If you want to use a normal distribution, then you need to filter out the non-normal samples. If you feel like you know what the standard deviation should be, you could remove everything from the sample above say 3 standard deviations away from the mean (the number 3 would have to depend on the sample size). This process can be done recursively to remove non-normal samples till you are happy with the size of the outlier in terms of the standard deviation.

Comment: I can't filter out those data,its the main problem here. Because in future, the present outliers may not be outliers as each sample data are pushed to the population. Thanks anyway for your reply.

Comment: Assuming that your problem is to drop outliers from a normal model with streaming data. You could start filtering after you have a significant statistical sample ... say 100 points ... call it the core sample. Do the above procedure on the core after you have 100 points. Then you monitor further data points and update the core with new points. Prevent new data that dont fit the core distribution into the core. This will allow slow changes in statistical properties of the core as well.

Comment: Great! we are working in log file clustering project. Log messages are written in broken English depending upon the application developer. Meaningful words may be known as outliers when treated existing English dictionary library. So, What we did is created a bag of words as dictionary for up coming messages. Lets an example here:
message1:Sep 26 bridge kernel: device usb0 entered promiscuous mode
message2:Sep 26 bridge kernel: device usb0 left promiscuous mode
The above messages are placed in a because left and entered have lower counts compare with other words. and they seem to be outliers.

Comment: If you accept an answer, you get points as well :) ... One company that does logfile analysis is: http://www.splunk.com/

Comment: I was waiting a better answer in fact!
Please write some better answer,I will surely accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatley the mean of a set of data is just that - the mean value. Are you sure that the point is actually an outlier? Your data contains what appears to be a single outlier with regards to the clustering, but if you take a look at your plot, you will see that this data does seem to have a linear relationship and so is it truly an outlier?

If this reading is really causing you problems, you could remove it entirely. Other than that the only thing that I could suggest to you is to calculate some kind of weighted mean rather than the true mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_mean . This way you can assign a lower weighting to the point when calculating your mean (although how you choose a value for the weight is another matter). This is similar to weighted regression, where particular data points have less weight associated to the regression fitting (possibly due to unreliability of certain points for example) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Weighted_linear_least_squares .

Hope this helps a little, or at least gives you some pointers to other avenues that you can try pursuing.

Comment: I tried to implement weighted mean but truly speaking, didn't applied yet! But, currently I don't have such any factors which can be applied as weight.
I will try with your suggestions very soon and I will reply if I could find solution with your concept. Thanks for your reply.